# Move SKSpriteNode in a Circle around Point

Tags: iphone, swift3

How i Can move a (image) SKSpriteNode around a Point (mid) with 90*? I have 4 Sprite Nodes and i want them on every press to move in a Circle around the mid with 90*. 
Can you help me? I'm working in SpriteKit with SWIFT 3!

Comment: Have you looked at this article or written any code? https://dezwitter.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/spritekit-with-swift-orienting-sprites-to-a-location/

Comment: I habe written a much of code, but the animation just doesn't work.. Can you post ne some Code? I want that they rotate just the Same way again and again.. And that in unser 0.05 Seconds. This Need to Look smooth :)

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: For now, i just switch the colors, like Ball.color = .gray.